# Confusion with comparison operators

Tags: c, if-statement

This solution is for the 1-12 exercise from the C programming language book. The question is to write a program that prints its input one word per line.

I found the following solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int c;
  int inspace;

  inspace = 0;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    {
      if(inspace == 0)
      {
        inspace = 1;
        putchar('\n');
      }
      /* else, don't print anything */
    }
    else
    {
      inspace = 0;
      putchar(c);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why is inspace == 0 used in the if argument and how the logic works later with inspace = 1 in the statements?

Does the 0 indicate space in the input?

Comment: It's being used as a boolean (true or false) and indicates if we are inside a sequence of whitespace charcters

Comment: Are you asking about the algorithm rather than the use of 0 and 1 as booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of C didn't have a boolean data type for "true" and "false".

Instead, they just used integers and decided that `0` means "false" and anything else means "true".

With this in mind part of the above code could be read like:

```
if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    {
      if(inspace == FALSE)
      {
        inspace = TRUE;
        putchar('\n');
      }
      /* else, don't print anything */
    }
    else
    {
      inspace = FALSE;
      putchar(c);
    }
```

Essentially, the logic is like:

- If the next character is the first white space character after something that wasn't white space (`inspace == FALSE`) print a newline character
- Otherwise if the next character is just more white space in the existing white space (`inspace == TRUE`) just ignore it
- Otherwise print it

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm flaws**

Although there may be some confusion with comparisons, there exist algorithm flaws.  Let us handle that first.

Should use `inspace = 1;` before the loop.

Add `if (!inspace) putchar('\n');` after the loop.

---

**Concerning comparisons when using a 2-state variable like `inspace`**

- Use `<stdbool.h>`.  It have been available since 1999.
- Code `inspace` as a `bool` and not an `int`.
- Drop the `==`, `!=`.

Do not code like `abd == true` or `def == false`.  Do not create `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c;
  bool inspace = true;  // Note this is the opposite state of OP's code.

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
      if(!inspace) {
        inspace = true;
        putchar('\n');
      }
      /* else, don't print anything */
    }
    else {
      inspace = false;
      putchar(c);
    }
  }

  if (!inspace) {
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Other improvements**

Use `<ctype.h>`

```
// if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
if (isspace(c))  // For all white-spaces, not just 3 of them.
```

Comment: *Bear with me as I'm new to this*
I am confused as to why inspace = true; is added in the if(!inspace) statement. 
According to the logic I applied it is:-
if(not true) 
{
inspace = true; 
newline;
}  
But if the condition is (not true) or (false) shouldn't it *not* carry out the newline function? Why is inspace = true; added?

Comment: @Odish Before the loop, code has `int inspace; inspace = 0;`.  I am suggesting that should initialize to 1, not 0.  I am not suggesting "inspace = true; is added in the if(!inspace) statement. ".  This answer does not change the algorithm of the loop.  `if(!inspace) {  inspace = true;` is like `if(inspace == FALSE)  {  inspace = TRUE;` but with `bool` variables